# What does $\nabla\times u$ mean in distributions?

Tags: notation, soft-question, curl

> What does $\nabla\times u$ mean in distributions?

Like obviously we associate $\nabla u\to\forall\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}):\langle -\nabla\varphi,u\rangle$ but what if $u(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and we were looking at the curl instead$?$

Comment: What do you mean by distributions? Usually $\nabla\times u$ is the curl of a vector field $u$, but you mention "curl" in the question.

Comment: "Distribution" in the sense of Schwartz ... generalized functions ... The basic theory is for scalar-valued generalized functions, so the OP asks how to do it for vector-valued generalized functions.

Comment: Are you in college $?$